# Select images without class name in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to select the images that have no class through my DOMDocument object.

I have the following

```
 $imgParser=new DOMDocument;

@$imgParser->loadHTML($html);

  foreach($imgParser->getElementsByTagName('img') as $imgNode){
        //the code below will display images with and without class name
        echo $imgParser->saveHTML($imgNode);

        //I can't user javascript at this point...

        //I need to save the images without class into my DB...
        //save to DB codes..

      }
```

Are there anyways to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DOMElement::hasAttribute()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.hasattribute.php) to determine whether a node has a particular attribute.

You can put this at the top of your loop body to skip that node:

```
if ($imgNode->hasAttribute('class')) {
    continue; // skip node if class attribute is present
}
```